# UIScrollview scale with ContentOffset

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm making an app that allows a user to import an image into a `UIScrollView` where they can scroll and position it. Other elements are places on top of the `UIScrollView`, and then an image is created by taking a snapshot of the entire view.

This works great and all is fine. Then I had to upload the image to Facebook. Facebook scales the image up significantly, so I need to increase the size of the images. So I should just scale up all of the elements and take a snapshot, that should work fine, right?

However, I cannot match the `contentOffset` of the `UIScrollView` after it is scaled up. I've tried all sorts of mathematical equations (some my own, others found here) and nothing seems to match the offset once scaled.

Conceptually, I would think this should work, but it doesn't:

```
    NSLog(@"Starting offset X: %f",self.imageScroll.contentOffset.x);
    NSLog(@"Starting offset Y: %f",self.imageScroll.contentOffset.y);

    self.imageScroll.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(4, 4);

    CGPoint offset = self.imageScroll.contentOffset;
    float newX = offset.x*4;
    float newY =  offset.y*4;
    NSLog(@"Scaled offset X: %f",newX);
    NSLog(@"Scaled offset Y: %f",newY);

    self.imageScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
```

I appreciate your time.

Comment: Try changing the transform of the image, not the scroll view. There are also *far better* ways to scale images.

Comment: you can directly scale the snapshot image. There is no need to scale your all views. I can give you function to scale image in any pixels if you want it.

Comment: Scaling the image up makes it blurry, that is why I need to make it big before the snapshot. I can't scale the image independently, because I need to crop and resize based on how the user  positioned/zoomed it into the scrollview.